# Arbitrary array length in java

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

Is there a way to get an array in java which is longer than the length supported by an integer data type?

I'm looking for something that may be indexable using a big integer in Java because the natively supported array length is nowhere near as big as I need it to be for an algorithm I am implementing.

Comment: Is it possible that you should not be implementing this algorithm with an array? Can you tell us a little about the algorithm? Btw, you can always implement a chunked array in your own class that is indexed by a long but I think it might be better to rethink the algorithm implementation.

Comment: If possible, I need arrays because they are faster; the array is a new prime sieve algorithm which works with arrays of numbers that are of primorial length, meaning that after the first couple of runs, the length will be greater than 9699690.

Comment: How high are you planning to have the sieve generate primes? Wouldn't you typically only go to 65,000 or some such and then use some prime probably test for primes larger than that? How will the array be used? If you will do something like "getNearestPrime( N )" then in the implementation of this method you can do a mod operation to find which array the solution is in. This will allow you to use multiple arrays.

Comment: I need arbitrary size because this is an additive sieve that uses the primes it generates to generate more based on new advancements in modular arithmetic. In other words, it can keep going forever until you stop it. I need to benchmark the algorithm against the Sieve of Atkin, AKS, and any of the faster wheel sieves for large lists of prime numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library should be useful for you: http://fastutil.dsi.unimi.it/

It says:

> "...provides also big (64-bit) arrays..."

Answer (score 3):

Int32 gives you <s>17</s> 8 gigabytes of storage. Do you have so much memory?

I think you should use sparse arrays, i.e. index elements by hash. For example, with just `HashMap<BigInteger,YourValueType>` or with some libs like BigMemory and alternatives http://terracotta.org/products/bigmemory

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you don't have to change the algorithm? `Integer.MAX` is equal to `2^31-1`, which is 2147483647, each `int` has 4 bytes what gives us: 8589934588 bytes of memory (8GB!!!).

Comment: Good point; I am looking to generate an array of several million primes, not for the list's sake, but for the sake of testing the function that generates them. I had read elsewhere that ints wouldn't cover it, but they probably should.

Comment: Note though, since this doesn't quite answer "arbitrary length," I have to pick an answer that does address that issue more directly. Voted up though.